# Wordpress ajax-admin returns JSON with php opening tag

Tags: php, json, ajax, wordpress

I am working on a website using Wordpress but all responses from admin-ajax.php have a php opening tag which throws errors.

Here is an example of a response when i try to search for a plugin in the "Add plugins" page of wordpress :

```
<?php{"success":true,"data":{"count":4399,"items":"<input type=\"hidden\" name= ... }}
```

It seems everytime ajax is used in the website, this problem shows up.

**Edit:**

I looked into my problem a bit more and here is what I found.

In the example I gave earlier, the file that makes the request is 'load-scripts.php'.
But the problem happens with any ajax request made by wordpress. For example, when I try to add a new user with a form (using User Registration plugin), the file that makes the request is 'user-registration.min.js' and the response still have the php tag inside :

```
<?php{"success":false,"data":{"message":["Username already exists.","Email already exists."]}}
```

**Edit 2:**

I found a way to fix my problem. It is kind of a dirty fix but it works.
As all my ajax responses had the php starting tag, I decided to filter all ajax responses and remove this tag.

I just added a small javascript code to do this.

```
// Fix php tag in ajax responses
(function($){
 $.ajaxSetup({
 dataFilter: function (response, type) {
    response = response.replace('<?php', '');
    return response;
 }
});

})(jQuery);
```

As I said, kinda dirty but it works.

Comment: show function that handles the ajax request.

Comment: @TheWolf I don't know which function handle the ajax request. It isn't something that I coded myself.
Is there a way to determine which function does the call?

Comment: Have you changed any library files like `admin-ajax.php` ?

Comment: @MalayM Not that I’m aware of. I compared the admin-ajax.php file from my site to one from a clean wordpress and there is no difference.

Comment: Please paste the ajax request javascript code for better understand.

Comment: @MalayM I don't know where to find the ajax javascript code. How can I find which function does the request?